# replacing static variable in the cod

Tags: ruby

```
class Numeric
 @@currencies = {'yen' => 0.013, 'euro' => 1.292, 'rupee' => 0.019}

  def method_missing(method_id, *args, &block) 
    singular_currency = method_id.to_s.gsub(/s$/, '')
    if @@currencies.has_key?(singular_currency) 
      self * @@currencies[singular_currency]
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

puts 3.yen
# Output is
# 0.039
```

My question is why wouldn't this code work if we replaced @@currencies with an instant variable @currencies and added attr_reader :currencies

Something like this

```
class Numeric
 @currencies = {'yen' => 0.013, 'euro' => 1.292, 'rupee' => 0.019}
 attr_accessor :currencies

  def method_missing(method_id, *args, &block) 
    singular_currency = method_id.to_s.gsub(/s$/, '')
    if @currencies.has_key?(singular_currency) 
      self * @currencies[singular_currency]
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

puts 3.yen
# Output
# method_missing': undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
#   from Untitled.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

Isn't 3 already an instant of a class Numeric, therefore,  the setter currencies should be able to work and return the proper hash combo?

EDIT: so method_missing is a static method then? Why isn't it defined with self.method_missing?

Comment: `method_missing` is an instance method, not a static method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
class Numeric
  @currencies = {'yen' => 0.013, 'euro' => 1.292, 'rupee' => 0.019}
  class << self
    attr_reader :currencies
  end
  def method_missing(method_id, *args, &block) 
    singular_currency = method_id.to_s.gsub(/s$/, '')
    if Numeric.currencies.key?(singular_currency) 
      self * Numeric.currencies[singular_currency]
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

The lines:

```
class << self
  attr_reader :currencies
end
```

create a read accessor for the class instance variable `@currencies`.

You may be inclined to write (as I did initially):

```
if self.class.currencies.key?(singular_currency)
```

but that doesn't work, because `method_missing` is invoked on `3`, an instance of `Fixnum`, a subclass of `Numeric`. Recall that subclasses don't have direct access to their ancestor's class methods. That's why we need to explicitly identify `Numeric` as the receiver.

As:

```
Fixnum.ancestors => [Fixnum, Integer, Numeric,...]
```

we see that:

```
if self.class.superclass.superclass.currencies.key?(singular_currency)
```

would work with `Fixnum`'s, but not with other subclasses of `Numeric`: `Bignum` and `Float`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `@currencies` within the context of a class declaration sets an instance variable on the class itself:

```
Numeric.instance_variable_get(:@currencies)
#=> {"yen"=>0.013, "euro"=>1.292, "rupee"=>0.019}
```

On the other hand, `@currencies` within the `method_missing` class and `currencies` accessor refers to the `@currencies` variable on a particular instance of numeric, which isn't defined:

```
Numeric.new.instance_variable_get(:@currencies)
#=> nil
```

You could fix this by defining the accessor on the class itself, and calling that accessor in the `method_missing` method:

```
class Numeric
  @currencies = {'yen' => 0.013, 'euro' => 1.292, 'rupee' => 0.019}
  class << self
    attr_accessor :currencies
  end

  def method_missing(method_id, *args, &block)
    singular_currency = method_id.to_s.gsub(/s$/, '')
    if self.class.currencies.has_key?(singular_currency)
      self * self.class.currencies[singular_currency]
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

Numeric.currencies
#=> {"yen"=>0.013, "euro"=>1.292, "rupee"=>0.019}
```

There's still a problem with this approach though. Even though the `currencies` accessor now refers to an instance variable on the class (and not an instance variable on a particular instance of that class as was the case before), `@currencies` is still only set on the `Numeric` class, not any of its subclasses:

```
Fixnum.currencies
#=> nil
```

To fix this, you can either modify the attribute accessor to automatically provide a default value for each individual class (so `Fixnum` and `Float` would each have their own separate `@currencies` variable), or go back to using class variables, like this:

```
class Numeric
  @@currencies = {'yen' => 0.013, 'euro' => 1.292, 'rupee' => 0.019}
  def self.currencies
    @@currencies
  end
  def self.currencies= new_currencies
    @@currencies = new_currencies
  end

  def method_missing(method_id, *args, &block)
    singular_currency = method_id.to_s.gsub(/s$/, '')
    if @@currencies.has_key?(singular_currency)
      self * @@currencies[singular_currency]
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

Numeric.currencies
#=> {"yen"=>0.013, "euro"=>1.292, "rupee"=>0.019}
Fixnum.currencies
#=> {"yen"=>0.013, "euro"=>1.292, "rupee"=>0.019}
1.yen
#=> 0.013
Numeric.currencies['bitcoin'] = 394.03
#=> 394.03
5.bitcoin
#=> 1970.1499999999999
```

Comment: Good answer. +1. It's very similar to mine, which I posted after yours. We were just thinking along the same lines, as I make it a practice to not read other answers before preparing my own. In fact, I sometimes don't read the question carefully enough, which can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Instance variable are only available on instances of a class. Class variables are available to the entire class.

In other words, the `@currencies.has_key?` in your code is undefined because it can't see the `@currencies` on line 2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're initializing `@currencies` outside of a method. Any code that isn't inside a method is evaluated in the context of *the class object*, not an *instance of the class*.

Take a look at this example class:

```
class Foo
  @bar = "baz"

  def self.bar; @bar; end

  def bar; @bar; end
end
```

Now let's look at the result of those two methods we defined.

```
Foo.bar     # => "baz"
Foo.new.bar # => nil
```

This means that `@bar` belongs to the `Foo` class, not an instance of `Foo`.

Your problem can be solved by initializing `@currency` in a method, typically `initialize`:

```
class Numeric
  def initialize
    @currency = ...
  end
end
```